# Meteor Deploy to .meteor.com Problems

Tags: meteor

I have been using meteor for quite awhile and have been deploying apps to `.meteor.com`. However recently after updating my app to meteor v0.8 and new collectionFS, the terminal states that the app has been deployed to `whatever.meteor.com` but when I go to the site, I see Meteor's `Site is down.Try again later`. I have narrowed it down to the new collectionFS package causing the problem, since my old app with the old collectionFS deploys fine. Any thoughts?

EDIT

The problem was due to the long startup time caused by my collectionFS `path:` definition.

Comment: Have you tried http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ ?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant for your situation. It's just a site that allows you to enter a URL and it will tell you if the site is down. Helps you to diagnose if it's your connection. I don't know anything about meteor.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah it says its down for everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Meteor app shut down repeatedly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070240/why-does-my-meteor-app-shut-down-repeatedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why your site may not load when being deployed.

### Site Inactivity

The `meteor deploy` service shuts down if your site hasn't been accessed in a while, and takes a while to start up again if it is requested, during which time you'll see that message.

In a few minutes after the first request, you should see the site come back up.

For more information, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072230/586086

### Excessive Resource Use

Another reason your site can refuse to deploy is if your app takes more than 4 minutes to start or uses an excessive amount of CPU - it will get killed. Is it doing anything resource-intensive like that? For initializing really big databases, do the initialization locally and copy the contents using the url from `meteor mongo -U yoursite.meteor.com`.

I had to do this for the [demo app for meteor-autocomplete](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete/tree/master/examples/pubsublocal). See the file `upload-db.sh`.

Comment: No that isn't the problem. I can't even deploy an app to `foo.meteor.com`. The terminal indicates that I have successfully uploaded the app, but when I try to navigate to it in chrome it says that the site is down. Can you deploy an app successfully to `meteor.com` right now? Im trying to figure out if it is just me or if everyone is having problems with it.

Comment: I have taken everything out of my Meteor.startup function and I still have the same issue. Recently I have upgraded my app to the new collectionFS ( https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). I can deploy my old app with the old collectionFS but not the one with the new collectionFS. It must be the startup time of the new collectionFS that is causing the long start-up time?

Comment: Would I observe this >4 min start time when I run it locally?

Comment: Yes, but a 2 min local start may become 5 min on a busy shared server. How long does a startup take after `meteor reset`?

Comment: it doesn't take longer than 15 seconds.

Comment: it must be something with collectionFS. I have posted an issue https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/288

Comment: For me the message appeared in the terminal, but the app's url works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
But the following solution works deploying the app successfully.

1. meteor login
2. meteor deploy < available meteor sub domain name >

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was just having the same issue and removing the collectionFS package solved my problem immediately...in case that helps anyone.